# Github: fork into new branch

Tags: github, fork, branch

I need to fork the branch from `PrestaShop:develop` into a different branch and not `username:develop`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork = clone repository of ***another*** user on `Github`, and make `GitHub` know about it

1) Fork the repo as usual with the `fork` button

2) If you want to rename the branch

```
git branch -m old_branch_name new_branch_name
git push origin :old_branch_name
git push origin new_branch_name
```

If you want to ***rename not branch but the whole repository*** - see, [How](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/).

---

If you want to have both branches in ***one*** repository, it is not a `GitHub` feature named `fork`, it is branching: `branch ...`, or `checkout -b`:

```
git checkout -b new_branch old_branch
git push -u origin new_branch
```

In that case you should not cope with `GitHub` forks to create a new branch from yours existing one.

Comment: I already have a `PrestaShop` repo so I will do the opposite, thank you

Comment: @UnLoCo Sorry, I did not read you question carefully. You want to rename a branch, not a repo, do you? I've fixed my answer.